# Running flask and socket server at the same time

Tags: python, sockets, flask

I would love some help, thanks!

I am trying to run a flask server and socket server at the same time, and it gives me the following error:

```
OSError: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
```

The program fails immediately. i tried to add this line before the bind,the socket server runs but the flask server not.

```
server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
```

I attached the code, thanks!

```
app = Flask(__name__)
IP = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 2000
ADRESS = (IP,PORT)

# open socket with client
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind(ADRESS)
server_socket.listen(1)
global client_socket
client_socket, address = server_socket.accept()
print(str(address)+ ' coonected')
app.run(host='127.0.0.1',debug=True)
```

Comment: Does it work once, fail for awhile then work once again? Put `server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)` before the bind so that you don't have "timed wait" issues.

Comment: It's does not work once, it fails immediately. i tried to add this line, but it's still does not work, it's runs only the socket server and not the flask server.